# How do you call to a specific location within a script from another script?

Tags: linux, fedora, zenity

I am trying to call to a specific function with a script from another script. This is just a text based game I am putting together for my kids to show what programming can do.  Its cheesy I know and I am using zenity as well, and yes I am aware there are better things out there but this is what I am using. And I am pretty new to linux so be gentle.

```
--radiolist --column "Pick" --column "Options" True "North." False "South." False "East." False "West." --width=600 --height=400)

case $walking in

"East.") hallway1 ;;
"West.") intersection ;;
"North.") ./maindeck.sh midHallway;;
"South.") ./maindeck.sh midHallway;;
```

I want to go to the location midHallway on the maindeck.sh from the original script commanddeck.sh instead of to the starting location.

Comment: You could have a `case` statement in `maindeck.sh` that does the appropriate action depending on the first parameter passed on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You could define functions in `maindeck.sh` and just call them as `$1`,

```
midHallway() {
  echo "here you are"
}

$1
```